# CakePHP 3 - Como somar os valores da coluna quantidade de várias linhas e mostrar o resultado na view?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3

Tenho a Tabela `Entradaestoques`

---

> id - prod - qtd
>
> 1  - sabão - 10
>
> 2  - pano  - 7
>
> 3  - sabão - 20
>
> 4  - desinfetante - 4
>
> 5  - sabão - 20
>
> 6  - pano  - 3

---

Quero mostrar na `View`

> Sabão: 50 unidades
>
> Pano: 10 unidades

---

Como faço para calcular a soma da quantidade do produto **sabão** e dos outros produtos no `controller` do `CakePHP` e enviar essa soma para mostrar na `View`?

Comment: Cadê o código?.

Comment: o CakePHP3 como é feito as `SQL`? tem algum código

Comment: não sei como posso fazer esse código no controller do cakePHP.

Comment: Você é iniciante em CakePHP? @ThiagoPhilipp

Comment: na versão 3.x sim, utilizava a antiga 2.x.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html sera que esse link ajuda, já visto a experiência da v2?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estava verificando esse tutorial mas não sie como utilizar no meu caso específico.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32589142/6797930 tem esse link olha só!

Comment: você tem algum Entidade pronta que faz referencia a essa tabela?

Comment: Entidade Produtoestoque criada pelo bake.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função **SUM()** do SQL e o ORM do cakePHP te dá meios de ter acesso fácil a ela. No seu caso, dentro do controller, é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

//Sua classe de tabela, diagamos que você tenha criado a classe de tabela: ProdutoEstoque.php
$produto = TableRegistry::get('EntradaEstoques');

$query = $produto->find();

$quantidade_sabao = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('sabao')]);

$quantidade_pano = $query->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('pano')]);

//Envia os valores para a view
$this->set([
    'quantidade_sabao' => $quantidade_sabao,
    'quantidade_pano' => $quantidade_pano,
]);
```

Dentro da view (Seu HTML) você terá acesso ao valor de cada variável:

```
<p>Quandidade de Sabão: <?= $quantidade_sabao ?></p>
```

Comment: Como faço para somar todas as linhas "qtd" com produtoestoque_id = 1, colocar esse resultado na variável $quatidade_prod1 e mostra essa informação na view?

Comment: Eu não tenho plena certeza, mas suspeito que seja possível utilizar o método where(), em conjunto com o método sum(). Ficaria algo como $quantidade = $query->select(['qtd' => $query->func()->sum('qtd')->where(['product_id' => 1]) ]), em seguida usa-se o método set(), pra incluir a variável e torná-la disponível na View.